# OneDrive API - SET Quota?

Tags: onedrive

Does anyone know if its possible to set the One-Drive quota to 0?  Client has a concern about data leakage, so I figure the fastest thing to do is to change the quota.  Unfortunately you cant do it though the UI (25 GB min).  And it looks like we only have a GET no SET.

Any ideas?

```
function getQuota() {
    WL.api({ path: "/me/skydrive/quota", method: "GET" }).then(
        function(response) {
            log(JSON.stringify(response).replace(/,/g, ",\n"));
        },
        function(response) {
            log("Could not access quota, status = " +
                JSON.stringify(response.error).replace(/,/g, ",\n"));
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API available to modify a user's quota.

Answer (score 0):

Quota is a representation of how much space is available to a user on OneDrive, due to a number of factors.  An similar scenario would be attempting to mark half of a 700mb CD-R disk unusable, there just isn't tooling build to handle that flow.

If you are worried about persisting state in OneDrive, I would recommend having that client move the sensitive data into a subfolder, and grant read-only access to other parties. You could check for changes with the 'modifiedDate' value on the folder to discover any modifications, but that is not a proactive but reactive approach.

Unfortunately OneDrive does not have a source control model built into its design, which is what it sounds like your customers needs.